# Creating new models not possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I would like to create a new model for a Ruby on Rails application. I know that this should do:

```
$ ruby script/generate model Book
```

But it gives me:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)
```

Why is that? How can I fix that? I am in my application folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of rails are you running? As far as I know it should be `script/rails` - but I am running rails 3.1.3

Edit: as @Jeremy bellow stated, in rails 3 and up it is `script/rails` - or of course, more generally, just `rails`

Run

```
ruby script/rails -h
```

and you should see the available commands

Run

```
ruby script/rails generate -h
```

to see what is available to generate

Alternatively, you should also just be able to run:

```
rails generate -h
```

I have never found the `ruby script/rails` portion to be necessary, it defaults to that automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 3, you do it like this:

```
$ rails generate model Book
```

The way you tried is the old way. Maybe you're following an old tutorial or something.

Comment: Great, that was it! It really seems to be an old tutorial. So are all former `ruby script/` now `rails generate `?

Comment: Basically. Run `rails -h` to see all possibilities